# Is a node always considered to be 0 volt when it's connected to a ground?

Tags: voltage, current

Can we directly say that a voltage at a node (voltage at point A) that shares a ground is always equal to 0 Volt? (I'm assuming right-side of the point A doesn't affect the solution as long as the rest of the circuit is completed.) or could it be greater than 0V, too? [image: circuit that has a node sharing a ground]

Answer (score 1):

For your standard circuit analysis type questions, yes.  Things get a little messier when real-world is concerned, especially at higher currents and higher frequencies where you can no longer assume that the connection between two points has zero resistance and zero inductance.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we directly say that a voltage at a node (voltage at point A) that shares a ground is always equal to 0 volt? ['V' or 'volt' by SI standard.]

Yes.

> (I'm assuming right-side of the point A doesn't affect the solution as long as the rest of the circuit is completed.) or could it be greater than 0V, too?

Correct. Despite the "pull-up" resistor the voltage at 'A' will always be 0 V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There are two things going on here.

The first being the assumption of the convention that ground is defined as zero volts.
The second is that, by definition, anything on the same node is the same voltage.
So A is the same voltage as ground, which is zero.

Now in real life, there might be some small resistance between A and ground and then they could have different voltages.